# Img_to_array returns blank value

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I have a image augmentation script which i use to perform some operations on images. But the img_to_array function of Keras returns Blank value on calling.

I have made the script for augmentation but it has been facing some issues.

```
from numpy import expand_dims
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from matplotlib import pyplot
from glob import glob
import glob
import cv2
import os


def get_images(m):
    count = 0
    img_list = []
    images_path = glob.glob(m)

    out = "C:\\Python35\\augmented_images\\horizontal_shift\\"

    if not os.path.exists(out):
        os.makedirs(out, exist_ok=True)

    for folder in images_path:
        for f in glob.glob(folder+"/*.jpg"):
            img_list.append(f)
            print(img_list)

        for i in range(len(img_list)):
            img_base = os.path.basename(img_list[i])
            img_name = os.path.splitext(img_base)[0]
            img = load_img(img_list[i])
            print(img)
            data = img_to_array(img)
            samples = expand_dims(data, 0)
            datagen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=[-200, 200])
            it = datagen.flow(samples, batch_size=1)
            for i in range(9):
                batch = it.next()
                cv2.imwrite(out + img_name+"_%d.jpg" % count, batch)
                count += 1


folders = ("C:\\Python35\\augment_img_data\\*")
get_images(folders)
```

Why is the img_to_array reutrn blank. What needs to be chnged so that the augmentation operation can be performed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I dont think you will have to expand the dimensions.

```
img = image.load_img(file, target_size=(224, 224))
img = image.img_to_array(img)
#x = resnet50.preprocess_input(img)
x = np.array([img])
feature = model.predict(x)
```

or this

```
img = load_img(img_list[i])
print(img)
data = img_to_array(img)
samples = expand_dims(data, axis= 1)
```